# Passing default argument in constructor QT Creator ( inherited class )

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i am trying to pass a default argument in a constructor but i can not figure out how it can be done since i am new to qt creator.
this is what i am trying
in the header file :

```
public:
    Compteur(QWidget *parent = nullptr , int variable= 5);
```

and in the cpp file :

```
Compteur::Compteur(QWidget *parent = nullptr, int variable) : QLabel(parent)
{

}
```

the error i am getting is :

```
error: default argument given for parameter 1 of 'Compteur::Compteur(QWidget*, int)' [-fpermissive]
 Compteur::Compteur(QWidget *parent = nullptr, int variable) : QLabel(parent)
```

The rest of the code :
the header file :

```
#ifndef COMPTEUR_H
#define COMPTEUR_H
#include <QtWidgets>

class Compteur : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT


    QString texte;
    int valeur;
    int valeurInitiale;

public:
    Compteur(QWidget *parent = nullptr , int valI = 5);
    void setText(const QString &);

public slots:
    void Decremente(){

    }

    void Reinitialise(){

    }
};

#endif // COMPTEUR_H
                        ^
```

and cpp file :

## include "compteur.h"

## include

```
Compteur::Compteur(QWidget *parent , int valI) : QLabel(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i have tried and it is showing me a new error : error: undefined reference to `vtable for Compteur'

Answer (score 0):

in your cpp file the parameters should be like this

```
Compteur::Compteur(QWidget *parent, int variable) : QLabel(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i have tried it and now it s giving me this error : error: undefined reference to `vtable for Compteur'

Comment: there is no way i can tell this error without seeing the code do you mind posting it?

Comment: i have added the code, i dont have much on it , i just started creating this class , the other class are working fine

Comment: add     virtual ~computer(); to your computer header file

Comment: Thnaks for the help @Spinkoo . it was a problem with the compiler, had to run the qmake before compiling , now it s working fine

Answer (score 0):

Just remove or comment

ifndef COMPTEUR_H

// heder file here

## endif // COMPTEUR_H

Comment: //ifndef COMPTEUR_H
#define COMPTEUR_H
#include <QtWidgets>

class Compteur : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT


    QString texte;
    int valeur;
    int valeurInitiale;

public:
    Compteur(QWidget *parent = nullptr , int valI = 5);
    void setText(const QString &);

public slots:
    void Decremente();

    void Reinitialise();
};

//#endif // COMPTEUR_H